# NVD3 scatter chart: implement click event handler

Tags: reactjs, nvd3.js

I am using `nvd3` scatter chart in `React` app. It looks like that:

[image]

I want to trigger a function when a user clicks one of the clusters on the image, passing the info about the cluster to the function. How would you approach this issue?

Comment: are each of those an object?

Comment: `.ng-group` - tag I think. See the code here: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/scatterChart.html     I can show how the html looks like if it helps

Comment: So, yes, I think so